# "Destroying" delegate on back button (Or swipe) [UINavigationController]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, rotation

**My problem:**

I have a navigation controller. When I navigate in to a specific part of the app, I initialize this code: http://rdsquared.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/circular-scrolling-inertia/

With this I have an image, which I can rotate with my finger. It uses a custom delegate. If the image rotates, and I press the back button (or swipe back) the app crashes.

In the code it says this:

```
// Taking a risk here that the delegate will not change or be destroyed while we're in the middle of animating the deceleration
if (self.delegate != NULL && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(rotationDidChangeByAngle:)]) {
```

And when the app crashes, it crashes at this point: (because the delegate gets destroyed when the user goes back)

```
[self.delegate rotationDidChangeByAngle:changeThisFrame];
```

I'm trying to understand and rewrite the code, that's why I keep referring to another persons source code.

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to rotate the image, and then press the back button while it's decelerating. (And then make the image stop offscreen)

Can anyone come up with a workaround to the delegate problem? Please check Ryan's source code for more information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [.h file](https://github.com/rdsquared09/CircularScrollInertia/blob/master/CircularScrollInertiaDemo/RDDRotationControlSurface.h#L54), he's marked the delegate as unsafe_unretained which is, uh, unsafe. If you change it to `weak` then the delegate will be nilled out automatically when it is deallocated, which should prevent the crash.

Alternatively, your delegate object could set the circular view's `delegate` property to nil, say, in its dealloc method, to get the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now. You don't want to know how much time I've spent on this! Much appreciated :)

Comment: I changed both the `@interface` to weak
and the 
`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<RotationControllerDelegate> delegate;` to weak. Should I change them both? Just making sure, so I know I did it properly. :)